# Is it possible to display table rows vertically with CSS?

Tags: html, css, html-table, vertical-alignment

I have a table like this:

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Phone no.</th>
      <th>Address</th>
      <th>Wealth</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>John Doe</th>
      <td>00123456789</td>
      <td>Morgue St. 21</td>
      <td>$100,000</td>
    </tr><tr>
      <th>Mary Sue</th>
      <td>00987654321</td>
      <td>Impossible St. 12</td>
      <td>$999,999,999,999,999</td>
    </tr><tr>
      <th>Cpt. Kirk</th>
      <td>00999999999</td>
      <td>Enterprise St. 22</td>
      <td>$100,000,000</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Well, this table is pretty wide. And now I have to make a stylesheet that would make the site appropriate for viewing on a narrow screen, like a mobile phone. So I have to do sth with this wide table.

I was thinking if this table could display vertically, not horizontally. More specifically, I was thinking if it could display more like this:

```html
<ul>
  <li><strong>John Doe:</strong>
    <ul>
      <li><em>Phone no.:</em> 00123456789</li>
      <li><em>Address:</em> Morgue St. 21</li>
      <li><em>Wealth:</em> $100,000</li>
    </ul>
  </li><li><strong>Mary Sue:</strong>
    <ul>
      <li><em>Phone no.:</em> 00987654321</li>
      <li><em>Address:</em> Impossible St. 12</li>
      <li><em>Wealth:</em> $999,999,999,999,999</li>
    </ul>
  </li><li><strong>Cpt. Kirk:</strong>
    <ul>
      <li><em>Phone no.:</em> 00999999999</li>
      <li><em>Address:</em> Enterprise St. 22</li>
      <li><em>Wealth:</em> $100,000,000 </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Now, I surely could make a Javascript that would transform the table code from the first snippet to the list code from the second snippet. But I wonder, if this is necessary? Is it possible to make a CSS stylesheet that, when attached to the table code from the first snippet would make it look like the second snippet?

Answer (score 8):

Sure, you can play with `media queries` and change the `display` of the `table` :

[See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mdzcry0e/7/)

```
@media(max-width: 640px){
  table, table td, table tr, table th { display: block; text-align: left; } 
  table th, table td { margin: 0; padding-left: 25px;  }
  table td  { margin-left: 40px;list-style: square; display: list-item; padding-left: 0; }
  table thead { display: none; }
}
```

Comment: Nice one, however why are the list-style items not shown in my browser (IE11)?

Answer (score 5):

```css
td, th {
  text-align: left;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}

thead {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Phone no.</th>
      <th>Address</th>
      <th>Wealth</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>John Doe</th>
      <td>00123456789</td>
      <td>Morgue St. 21</td>
      <td>$100,000</td>
    </tr><tr>
      <th>Mary Sue</th>
      <td>00987654321</td>
      <td>Impossible St. 12</td>
      <td>$999,999,999,999,999</td>
    </tr><tr>
      <th>Cpt. Kirk</th>
      <td>00999999999</td>
      <td>Enterprise St. 22</td>
      <td>$100,000,000</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Here's a possible way without the `<thead>` elements, but you could create hidden elements before each person, e.g. `<span class="hidden">Name:</span> Cpt. Kirk` and then enable all the hidden elements with media queries. Not the most elegant solution, I'd probably prefer JS for this.

Comment: Works Great! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There might be better ways to do this, but here is a solution to reach the goal:

```
table thead{
  display:none;
}    
table tbody tr th{
  display:block;
  text-align: left;
}
table tbody tr td{
 display:block;
 margin-left:20px;
}
table tbody tr th::before{
 content:"• ";
}
table tbody tr td::before{
 content:"◊ ";
}
```

Find a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/ktnurvfr/

Answer (score 0):

You can change the table elements to display block and force them to act like block elements just add this class to your table.

```
.vertical-table thead{
display:none;
}
.vertical-table tr, .vertical-table th, .vertical-table td{
display:block;
width:100%;
}
```

```css
.vertical-table thead{
display:none;
}
.vertical-table tr, .vertical-table th, .vertical-table td{
display:block;
width:100%;
}
```

```html
<table class="vertical-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Phone no.</th>
      <th>Address</th>
      <th>Wealth</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>John Doe</th>
      <td>00123456789</td>
      <td>Morgue St. 21</td>
      <td>$100,000</td>
    </tr><tr>
      <th>Mary Sue</th>
      <td>00987654321</td>
      <td>Impossible St. 12</td>
      <td>$999,999,999,999,999</td>
    </tr><tr>
      <th>Cpt. Kirk</th>
      <td>00999999999</td>
      <td>Enterprise St. 22</td>
      <td>$100,000,000</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code :

```
@media(max-width: 640px){
table, table td, table tr, table th { display: block; text-align: left; } 
table th, table td { margin: 0; padding-left: 25px;  }
table td  { margin-left: 40px;list-style: square; display: list-item;   padding-left: 0; }
table thead { display: none; } 
}
```

i will be work.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. During my search I encountered this elegant solution by sergiopinnaprato: http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/no-more-tables-respsonsive-table

On smaller screens it changes the table to a single column. Very readable solution using only html and css code:

HTML:

```
<div id="no-more-tables">
        <table class="col-md-12 table-bordered table-striped table-condensed cf">
            <thead class="cf">
                <tr>
                    <th>Code</th>
                    <th>Company</th>
                    <th class="numeric">Price</th>
                    <th class="numeric">Change</th>
                    <th class="numeric">Change %</th>
                    <th class="numeric">Open</th>
                    <th class="numeric">High</th>
                    <th class="numeric">Low</th>
                    <th class="numeric">Volume</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td data-title="Code">AAC</td>
                    <td data-title="Company">AUSTRALIAN AGRICULTURAL COMPANY LIMITED.</td>
                    <td data-title="Price" class="numeric">$1.38</td>
                    <td data-title="Change" class="numeric">-0.01</td>
                    <td data-title="Change %" class="numeric">-0.36%</td>
                    <td data-title="Open" class="numeric">$1.39</td>
                    <td data-title="High" class="numeric">$1.39</td>
                    <td data-title="Low" class="numeric">$1.38</td>
                    <td data-title="Volume" class="numeric">9,395</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td data-title="Code">AAD</td>
                    <td data-title="Company">ARDENT LEISURE GROUP</td>
                    <td data-title="Price" class="numeric">$1.15</td>
                    <td data-title="Change" class="numeric">+0.02</td>
                    <td data-title="Change %" class="numeric">1.32%</td>
                    <td data-title="Open" class="numeric">$1.14</td>
                    <td data-title="High" class="numeric">$1.15</td>
                    <td data-title="Low" class="numeric">$1.13</td>
                    <td data-title="Volume" class="numeric">56,431</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {

/* Force table to not be like tables anymore */
#no-more-tables table, 
#no-more-tables thead, 
#no-more-tables tbody, 
#no-more-tables th, 
#no-more-tables td, 
#no-more-tables tr { 
    display: block; 
}

/* Hide table headers (but not display: none;, for accessibility) */
#no-more-tables thead tr { 
    position: absolute;
    top: -9999px;
    left: -9999px;
}

#no-more-tables tr { border: 1px solid #ccc; }

#no-more-tables td { 
    /* Behave  like a "row" */
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee; 
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 50%; 
    white-space: normal;
    text-align:left;
}

#no-more-tables td:before { 
    /* Now like a table header */
    position: absolute;
    /* Top/left values mimic padding */
    top: 6px;
    left: 6px;
    width: 45%; 
    padding-right: 10px; 
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-align:left;
    font-weight: bold;
}

/*
Label the data
*/
#no-more-tables td:before { content: attr(data-title); }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: I added some sample code from the original source as to clarify the solution provided by the external link.